# cloud vision API responds with 403 every time

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Vision API alway responding with 403

```
 const buffer = await selectedFile.arrayBuffer();
 const imageBytes = Buffer.from(buffer).toString("base64");

 let body = JSON.stringify({
          requests: [
            {
              image: {
                content: imageBytes,
              },
              features: [{ type: "TEXT_DETECTION" }],
            },
          ],
        }); 
let response = await fetch(
          "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=" +
            GOOGLE_API_KEY,
          {
            method: "post",
            body: body,
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );
        response.json();
        console.log(response);
```

Trying to run Cloud vision tried with multiple project and API keys even fresh one no luck

Comment: This is not causing your problem, but to parse the JSON from the response you need `response = await response.json();`

Comment: it's sending me 403 response man it's have nothing to do with the response.json()  thanks anyway

Comment: Why do not you add a OAuth access token in the header of your request? The API key is not the recommended way.

Comment: well this is an in-house app and there is no authentication built for this that's why anyway the issue is resolved it was an issue with the billing account being suspended